# Rails + Passenger + Nginx 404 Not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger, redmine

I'm working with Rails + Passenger + Nginx

My project (Redmine) is in /var/www/tracker-continuity/current (and project in public).

I don't know why when I try to access to my serveur it's always a 404 Error page. We can see it in log

```
[ N 2018-06-05 14:23:20.6491 20067/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1236 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ N 2018-06-05 14:23:20.6494 20067/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:251 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ N 2018-06-05 14:23:20.6631 20067/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:971 ]: Passenger core online, PID 20067

2018/06/05 14:23:31 [error] 20084#20084: *1 "/var/www/trackeur-continuity/current/public/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: someIp, server: hideUrl, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "hideIp"
```

Here, part of my `nginx.conf` and my vhost conf. Extracted from a Nginx dump configuration. (Only Passenger parts)

```
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid  /var/run/nginx.pid;
user  www-data;
worker_processes  4;


include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

http {

    ...
}


# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/mod-http-passenger.conf:
### Begin automatically installed Phusion Passenger config snippet ###
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
passenger_ruby /usr/bin/passenger_free_ruby;
### End automatically installed Phusion Passenger config snippet ###


}

server {

listen 80;
server_name default_server ;

charset utf-8;
root /var/www/trackeur-continuity/current/public;

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log timed_combined buffer=16k;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

passenger_enabled on;
rails_env development;
client_max_body_size 110m;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Got it !**

`tracker-continuity` not `trackeur-continuity`